# Unable to isolate correct clientHeight value

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I had to create a quick and dirty expand/collapse functionality to replicate existing behavior that did not require the use of jQuery as the existing method uses jQuery and has some conflicts that require significant debugging to resolve.

Originally I had decided to use pure CSS but couldn't think of a way to make it infinitely scalable if necessary, so I opted to use a little bit of JavaScript to make the magic work.

I will post the code, explain it and then illustrate in a fiddle:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function cflExpandingContent(e, b) {
        e = document.getElementById(b);

        if(e.style.height != '25px') {
            e.style.height = '25px';
        } else {
            c = document.querySelector('.cflExpandContent, .' + b);
            e.style.height = e.clientHeight + c.clientHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.expandable {
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
         transition: all 1s;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Begin Expand/Collapse -->
<div id="sbb1" class="expandable" style="height: 25px;">
    <a href="#!" onclick="cflExpandingContent(this, 'sbb1'); return false">CLICK HERE TO EXPAND >></a>
    <ul class="cflExpandContent sbb1">
        [cflproducts]ProductName[/cflproducts]
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End Expand/Collapse -->
```

**Wordpress Shortcode:**

```
function get_brand_products( $atts, $brand = null ) {

    $prods = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'product_cat' => "$brand",
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title' ) );

        foreach( $prods as $prod ) {
            $products .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $prod->ID ) . '">' . $prod->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }
    return $products;
}

add_shortcode( 'cflproducts', 'get_brand_products' )
```

So, starting from the bottom up, the shortcode hooks into the pre-existing WooCommerce database, and retrieves all products for a given brand, loops through the products and builds a list of **li** elements containing links and titles.

The HTML has a **div** which contains the custom shortcode tag and defines the brand parameter to be passed to the function. The **div** is set to a fixed height with the overflow set to hidden via CSS.

What's shown is a link with an onclick event that triggers a JavaScript placed in the footer of the theme.

The script takes two parameters, the current element that is triggering the function call: **this** and the unique element identifier (ID). This is done because there is a grid of 6 such blocks, and I wanted the code to be as reusable as possible.

Taking the script parameters, it first gets the **div** element being manipulated, then does a check; if the style="height: 25px" isn't 25px, it sets it to 25px (this is the "collapse" mechanism). However if the element height IS 25px ie, it's "closed" it get's the (supposed to anyway) full height value of the element, including the hidden content.

What happens is when the element height is set to a fixed amount, the CSS transition code kicks in and shows a smooth open/close animation.

Here is the Fiddle with dummy content to illustrate different heights: https://jsfiddle.net/5uzxLd5p/8

The code technically "works" but not to my satisfaction. When the script runs **c = document.querySelector('.cflExpandContent, .' + b);** it isn't grabbing the correct element, it's defaulting to:

```
<ul class="cflExpandContent sbb1">...</ul>
```

Irrespective of the link that is activated. Ie, if sbb2 is clicked, it still looks for and grabs sbb1's .cflExpandContent UL.

If I instead hardcode the element height to be 'auto' it correctly opens whichever element to the proper height, but breaks the CSS transition.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

Such a bone headed mistake/oversight.

Issue was me deliminating the CSS classes for the UL tag instead of combining them.

Working code:

```
<script>
    function cflExpandingContent(e, b) {
        e = document.getElementById(b);

        if(e.style.height != '25px') {
            e.style.height = '25px';
        } else {
            c = document.querySelector('.cflExpandContent.' + b);
            e.style.height = e.clientHeight + c.clientHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>
```

~ fin ~